# if statement not working when the variable does have a value

Tags: batch-file

So in this code !msp! in the echo outputs 0.

I am doing a check to see what that number is and then echo out the type.  But for some reason its saying none of the if statements are true?

```
set msp=
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic memorychip get memorytype /value ^| find "="') do (set msp=%%f)
echo !msp!
if !msp!=="0" ( 
echo Unknown s
)

if !msp!==0 ( 
echo Unknown n
)
```

The s and n is just me trying to see if " " matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"0"` is not equal to `0`. Quote *both* sides of the equation. But that alone does not solve your problem. `Wmic` returns an ugly line ending of `CRCRLF` instead of just `CRLF`. The additional `CR` gets part of the variable (try `echo a!msp!b` with your code). One way (actually the most reliable) to solve that, is with another `for`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "msp="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic memorychip get memorytype /value ^| findstr "="') do for %%g in (%%f) do set "msp=%%g"
echo !msp!
if "!msp!" == "0" ( 
  echo Unknown s
)
if !msp! == 0 ( 
  echo Unknown n
)
```

In this special case (output is a number), also `set /a` works:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic memorychip get memorytype /value ^| findstr "="') do set /a msp=%%f
```

Comment: /a converted it to a number as needed with out the extra cr stuff... worked great! thanks

Comment: just remember the first method, should you expect a string someday `;)`